# Exist there the limits defined below?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

I have a set of locally Lipschitz continuous, continuously differentiable functions ${{x}_{i}}:\mathbb{R}_{0}^{+}\to \mathbb{R}_{0}^{+}$ ($i=1,2,...,n$). Denote the independent variable with $t$. Suppose, there are ${{\eta }_{1}},{{\eta }_{2}},\ldots ,{{\eta }_{n}}\in {{\mathbb{R}}^{+}}$ (strictly positive) coefficients such that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}{{{\eta }_{i}}{{x}_{i}}\left( t \right)}=c$ for all $t\ge 0$, where $c\in \mathbb{R}^{+}$. Furthermore, ${{x}_{i}}\left( t=0 \right)>0$ for all $i$. I would like to ask if there exists a strictly positive limit $\underset{t\to \infty }{\mathop{\lim }}\,{{x}_{i}}\left( t \right)$ for all $i$ in this case. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is there a missing assumption? What is preventing one (or all) of the $x_i$ to be identically $0$?

Comment: Oh, you are right! The parameters $c$ and ${{x}_{i}}\left( t=0 \right)$ should be strictly positive for all $i$.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is negative:
consider $n = 2$, $\eta_1 = \eta_2 = 1$, $x_1(t) = \frac{1}{1 + t}$ and $x_2(t) = 2 - \frac{1}{1 + t}$.

Then $x_1,x_2$ have the correct regularity, they only take positive values and are strictly positive at $0$. By construction $x_1(t) + x_2(t) = 2$ for every $t \ge 0$, but $x_1(t) \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$.

Comment: They don't need to have a limit: play with the cosine!

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you all for your efforts. Does someone know how the hypotheses can be minimally restricted such that the strictly positivity should be in force? I have specified the problem in more detail on the site http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1848922/exist-there-the-limits-of-the-functions-defined-below.

Answer (score 0):

For $n=2,$ the functions $2-\cos t, 2+\cos t$ satisfy the hypotheses, but neither function has a limit at $\infty.$